# In Linux shell script how do I print the largest and smallest values of an array?

Tags: bash, sh

I don’t really understand much about arrays, but I need to know how to find and print the largest and smallest values of an array. The array is predefined by a read command, and the user will be prompted to enter n amount of integers.

How would I assign the read input to an array and find and display the largest and smallest values of the array?

Is there a way to test the array elements to see if they are all integers?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a integers

biggest=${integers[0]}
smallest=${integers[0]}

for i in ${integers[@]}
do
     if [[ $i -gt $biggest ]]
     then
        biggest="$i"
     fi

     if [[ $i -lt $smallest ]]
     then
        smallest="$i"
     fi
done

echo "The largest number is $biggest"
echo "The smallest number is $smallest"
```

Comment: what are the attempts that you have made yet?

Comment: This question can be answered looking at the documentation, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html . Or do you have more specific problem? Some sample code would not hurt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general idea is to iterate through the array once and keep track of what the `max` and `min` seen so far at each step.

Some comments and explanations in-line (prefixed by `#`)

```
# This is how to declare / initialize an array:
arrayName=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

# Use choose first element of array as initial values for min/max;
# (Defensive programming) - this is a language-agnostic 'gotcha' when
# finding min/max ;)
max=${arrayName[0]}
min=${arrayName[0]}

# Loop through all elements in the array
for i in "${arrayName[@]}"
do
    # Update max if applicable
    if [[ "$i" -gt "$max" ]]; then
        max="$i"
    fi

    # Update min if applicable
    if [[ "$i" -lt "$min" ]]; then
        min="$i"
    fi
done

# Output results:
echo "Max is: $max"
echo "Min is: $min"
```

Comment: how would i do this with an array thats elements are declared by the user?

Comment: @user1864478 you would need to provide a lot of missing details regarding that (and other aspects of your problem) in an edit to your question. Right I'm only providing a very generalize example of how to use arrays in bash since there's a lack of context.

Comment: @user1864478 Change `for i in ${integers[0]}` to `for i in ${integers[@]}`; big difference between `0` and `@` =)

Comment: would there be a way to test if the elements of the array are all integers?

Comment: @BobbyT28 This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634429/in-linux-shell-script-how-do-i-print-the-largest-and-smallest-values-of-a-array/72099479#72099479 "bash function is_int_array()") includes a bash function that solves the test for all integers piece.

Answer (score 6):

Try this if you need to **compare** (signed or not) **INTegers** :

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( -10 1 2 3 4 5 )

min=0 max=0

for i in ${arr[@]}; do
    (( $i > max || max == 0)) && max=$i
    (( $i < min || min == 0)) && min=$i
done

echo "min=$min
max=$max"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
min=-10
max=5
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `arr=( )` is the declaration of the array
- `((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression
- `[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`
- `foo || bar` runs bar when foo fails: `[[ -d $foo ]] || { echo 'ohNoes!' >&2; exit 1; }`
- `cmd1 && cmd2` : cmd1 is executed, and then if its exit status was 0 (true), cmd2 is executed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: what happens when `arr=(-1 -2 -3 -4)`? ;)

Comment: Try `arr=(-1 -2 -3 -4)` with your edited version for integers: it gives `min=-4 max=0`. There's a small gotcha with your min/max initialization.

Answer (score 3):

A funny way using sort:

if you have an array of integers, you can use `sort` to sort it, then select the first and last elements to have the min and max elements, as in:

```
{ read min; max=$(tail -n1); } < <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n)
```

So if you want to prompt user for say 10 integers, check that the user entered integers and then sort them, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=10
array=()

while ((n));do
   read -p "[$n] Give me an integer: " i
   [[ $i =~ ^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
   array+=($i)
   ((--n))
done

# Sort the array:
{ read min; max=$(tail -n1); } < <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n)
# print min and max elements:
echo "min=$min"
echo "max=$max"
```

Comment: Nothing relevant to a beginner... (IMHO)

Comment: @sputnick yeah but at least it works, unlike your solution `;-)`

Comment: I think you have not tested it to say this... Works well.

Comment: no math! [ingenious classification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269777/what-about-a-more-flexible-voting-system-favorites-bookmarks-kudos-and-even-s) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to find maximum and minimum values from an array of n integers.

```
#author@Pratham
declare -a arr
echo "How many numbers you want to enter?"
read n
echo "Enter the Array Elements"
for(( i=0 ; i<$n ; i++))
do
    read array_elements
    arr[$i]="$array_elements"
done
echo "The Array Elements are :"
echo -e "${arr[@]}"
max=${arr[0]}
min=${arr[0]}
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    if [[ $i -gt $max ]];
    then
        max=$i
    fi
    if [[ $i -lt $min ]];
    then
        min=$i
    fi
done
echo "Maximum element in the array is: $max"
echo "Manimum element in the array is: $min"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array, then the first and last elements will be your min and max values:

```sh
sorted=($(IFS=$'\n'; sort -n <<< "${integers[*]}"))
echo "The largest number is ${sorted[-1]}"
echo "The smallest number is ${sorted[0]}"
```

To test if an array is all integers, you could use the following bash function:

```sh
is_int_array() {
    for e in "$@"; do
        [[ "$e" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] || return 1
    done
    return 0
}
```

To use the function:

```sh
is_int_array "${integers[@]}" && echo 'is int array' || echo 'not all integers'
is int array

is_int_array 'a' 1 2 3  && echo 'is int array' || echo 'not all integers'
not all integers

is_int_array 1 2 3 -4 && echo 'is int array' || echo 'not all integers'
is int array
```