# Bash command that displays first the oldest of the given dates, and then the youngest date

Tags: bash, awk

What would a command that displays youngest and oldest dates look like? The input is given by default so it should be one without using a file directory.
For example:

```
1910-04-21
2015-03-05
1930-01-23
1908-06-02
2015-07-13
```

From which the result should be:

```
1908-06-02
2015-07-13
```

I tried using AWK for it, but how can I write it?

Comment: Why isn't there *any* effort to find the duplicate? It is likely a common homework assignment. With [23,705,499 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), duplicates must abound. Some candidates (and related): *[How to use AWK to search for min and max values of column in certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162181/)*, *[Maximum and minimum for 10 numbers in a Linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923136/)*, *[Maximum and Minimum using AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709507/)*,

Comment: cont' - *[In Linux shell script how do I print the largest and smallest values of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634429/)*, *[Unix Scripting - Finding Minimum and Maximum (Bash Shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534563/)* (*"My code below is part of an assignment"*), *[Finding max and minimum values from a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642558/)*, *[Find the minimum number in a file using a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470061/)*,

Comment: cont' - *[Need help to find average, min and max values in shell script from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034729/)*, *[Minimum and maximum value in a column for a task in a Unix file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766063)*,

Comment: Here is one with slightly more complicated input (thus an answer could be a simplified version of one of the answers): *[Finding the max and min values and printing the line from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212410/)*

Comment: Here is one with the same kind of input, but only the minimum is asked for: *[Get smallest line in a file (smallest based on string lexicographic order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707053/)* (by "smallest" was probably meant the value, not the length)

Answer (score 5):

Just sort and print the first and last lines.

```
sort | sed -n '1p; $p'
```

Comment: I edited the question because this wasnt what I looked for, I want to find youngest and oldest dates in the file

Comment: @BigChain, that's what the provided solution does.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the input format (i.e., each line is yyyy-mm-dd), you can do this as well,

```
awk '{ if ($1 > M) M=$1; if (!m || $1 < m) m=$1; } END { print m; print M } infile'
```

where `m` and `M` stand for minimum and maximum respectively.

The disadvantage with respect to [oguz ismail's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207039/bash-command-that-displays-first-the-oldest-of-the-given-dates-and-then-the-you/76207099#76207099) is that it is much longer and less readable.

The advantage is that the complexity is linear in the number of lines instead of `sort` complexity (more than linear, in general), because no sorting is attempted, only the minimum and maximum are retrieved.

---

Since undefined variables, when used, are effectively empty strings and since `"non-empty-string" > ""`, `$1 > M` will work also the first time, when `M` is undefined; on the other hand, `$1 < m` would not work the first time, so the conditional is changed to `!m || $1 < m`, where the first operand, `!m`, is `true`/`1` when `m` is empty, i.e., the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Using any AWK:

```
awk 'NR==1{min=max=$1} $1<min{min=$1} $1>max{max=$1} END{print min ORS max}' file
```

Output:

```
1908-06-02
2015-07-13
```

Answer (score -2):

You can literally chain them up like this and still be fully [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliant:

```
echo '
2015-03-05
1908-06-02
2015-07-13
1930-01-23
1910-04-21' |
```

---

```
mawk '{ !__?__=___=$_:___<$_?___=$_:$_<__?__=$_:_ } END { print "min ::", __
                                                          print "max ::", ___ }'
```

#### Output

```
min :: 1908-06-02
max :: 2015-07-13
```